# Button Click Event not updating textbox until Finished

Tags: c#, multithreading

Here's a C# code, What happens is when `qsubmit` button is clicked, program straight away displays "wait..!".

When I debug the program it is found that when I click and function executes `textbox1.text = "Hello";` but doesn't updates textbox, it updates only when the control goes off the event function, when that happens value of textbox has already been changed to `"wait..!"`. I want to know why it doesn't updates textbox instantly(If that would have done, I would have seen the text during `Thread.Sleep()`)

```
 private void Button_QSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      textBox1.Text = "Hello";
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      textBox1.Text = "Wait..!";  
 }
```

Comment: You are blocking the message pump with the `Thread.Sleep()` and so it won't update the screen.  You probably could call `textBox1.Update()` to force an immediate redraw

Comment: @Salim - This also doesn't have anything to do with multi-threading. The UI thread is all you are using here. It's a single thread that you're blocking with your `Thread.Sleep` call.

Comment: So what should I use for delaying execution of statement, like this?  My task was to display some text wait for half second and update/

Comment: @Salim https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI thread is responsible to redraw the windows. So as **long**  as you are doing this inside the UI Thread (e.g. a Button click event), the process is busy with your code and the window is not drawn.

A easy solution could be the use of an Timer. Just add an timer and in the button click you start it (e.g. you set itup to fire in 1 second).

The Timer Event then will simply set the Text.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx shows details about the Timer class.

Answer (score 2):

You are hanging the UI Thread by calling Thread.Sleep from the Main Thread (UI), to update the text box you have to let the UI thread do its job outside your function to update the UI..anyway call `Application.DoEvents()` before the sleep.  **But calling `Application.DoEvents()` is a bad design**

Comment: Don't event suggest `Application.DoEvents()`. It's bad and only there for legacy support of VB6 apps.

Comment: @Enigmativity you are absolutely correct, but i think it is for an educational purposes :) –  Ahmad just now   edit

Comment: @Ahmad You are welcome good sir.  You already rightly indicated it was a _bad design_,  I just made it more obvious. :)

Comment: What should I do, I mean if i want to Display some text, wait for half a second display another on a button click event.